# ondragenter do not affect children

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Is there any way to do not fire the `ondragleave` event when dragging hover a children?

```
<div ondragenter="entered()" ondragleave="left()">
    <a href="#">children element</a>
</div>
```

Here an example: http://jsfiddle.net/6uu7h/4/ (Chrome)

I do not want that when entering the children it fires the event `ondragleave` since it did not really left the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an example: http://jsbin.com/ahipas/4/edit

```
$(function() {
  var destination;

  $('#bidi').on('dragenter', function(event) {
    destination = event.target;
    $('#debug').append("ENTERED ELEMENT<br />");
  });

  $('#bidi').on('dragleave', function(event) {
    if (!$(this).find(destination).size() && !$(this).find(event.target).size()) {
      $('#debug').append("LEFT ELEMENT<br />");
    }
  });
});
```